electronic properties simulation from experimental structure, good idea?
Good day to everyone !
I am currently in a physical chemistry internship trying to simulate a Raman spectrum of a molecular crystal using DFTB. Innocently, I directly tried to calculate the normal modes, then the Raman spectrum.
One of the researchers in the lab told me that this is wrong, and that I should optimize the geometry of the unit cell I have before further calculations. I don't understand that. He told me that this is because we want to be sure the structure is in a local minimum for the specific technique used to simulate. Can anyone enlighten me on what this means ? I am not sure I get it. To me an experimental XRD is superior, why should I optimize the geometry ?

Short answer: No, it is not a good idea. The maths assume you are at a minimum, and if you don't follow the assumption you have a reasonable probability of getting unphysical results. You must optimise first. If get more time will expand, but can't face MathsJax this evening.
